# R loop to apply same function to multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops

I have multiple dataframes where I need to apply the same function (unique)

```
df1 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:6,7,7,6,2,1))
df2 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:10,7,7,6,2,1,10,9,3))
```

In each of the df I want to apply the following function to show me unique list of individuals:

```
individuals1 = data.frame(length(unique(df1[,1])))
individuals2 = data.frame(length(unique(df2[,1])))
```

Here we have **7** and **10** unique IDs. This is easy but the problem is that sometimes I have more than just 2 df.
How can I apply the unique function to all dataframes and have **1 output** dataframe that gives me the number of unique individuals per df like this:

```
output = data.frame(Index = c("Unique.ID"), df1 = c(7),df2=c(10))

#index df1 df2
#Unique.ID 7 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could achieve this. Here's one approach that uses functions from the `dplyr` package

```r
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df1 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:6,7,7,6,2,1))
df2 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:10,7,7,6,2,1,10,9,3))

# combine the dataframes into a named list, for convenience
df_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

# bind, group, and summarise
bind_rows(df_list, .id = "df_name") %>%
  group_by(df_name) %>%
  summarise(n_unique = length(unique(Bird_ID)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   df_name n_unique
#>   <chr>      <int>
#> 1 df1            7
#> 2 df2           10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: As used by @Yuriy below, if you have many dataframes it may be easier to compile them into a list using something like `mget(ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "df[0-9]+"), envir = globalenv())` (assuming each dataframe follows a consistent naming pattern)

Answer (score 1):

```r
df1 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:6,7,7,6,2,1))
df2 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:10,7,7,6,2,1,10,9,3))

l <- mget(x = ls(pattern = "df"))

library(tidyverse)
map_df(l, ~n_distinct(.x[[1]]))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>     df1   df2
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     7    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**base**

```
sapply(l, function(x) length(unique(x[[1]])))

df1 df2 
  7  10
```